# Cannot start server with wrong /etc/network/interfaces config

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization, interface

I removed the last 3 lines bellows:

BEFORE:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
        address __IP___
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway __IP___
```

AFTER:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
```

Then I hit a **reboot** action and cannot start + access server anymore.

- How can I do now?
- Can I still save my data?

Supporter gave me a KVM account to access KVM and I see a Server Manager, I don't know how to use it to connect to my server in the data center while my server is offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In thais line `iface enp4s0 inet static` you want to make your ip static but you have not specified the gateway, netmask and IP address. Then how your server will get an IP address? The only solution is that you connect the hard drive of the server to another pc, edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` config file and reconnect the hard disk. If you want that DHCP should assign an IP to the server, then delete `static` from `iface enp4s0 inet static`.

Comment: Connecting the drive is not the only way. If you can access console via for instance KVM, this would be the primary way of fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment because of low rep. I will just post an answer.

Your machine will boot up but it will not be available from outside since you did not define static IP address which network manager expects.

So to fix that, you have been given KVM access to that this machine, please note that machine needs to be up and running for KVM access to work, in which case you will have a command line, for example, similar to putty, from which you can login as root and make necessary changes.

From what I recall KVM access is considered as local access (maybe I need correction on that).

Please do note that there is an difference between KVM as [Kernel-based Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) and KVM as [keyboard, video and mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch), and in your case keyboard, video and mouse is probably correct one.

Comment: My server is Ubuntu, but when I access server via port using KVM, It's a Window server. Seem to supportor gave me a wrong account, right?

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems so, anyhow you should be able to access your own machine from some kind of "Control Panel" as it usually comes with KVM. Maybe you should ask for iLO, IPMI or IDRAC or in case of VM, KVM access for your own machine which is faulty.